# Sorting by ID and then by timestamp within the same node

Tags: xslt, sorting, timestamp, xslt-1.0

I have a very particular issue regarding sorting with XSL 1.0 (and only 1.0 - I'm using .Net Parser).

Here is my xml :

```
<Root>
....
<PatientsPN>
        <Patient>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165910</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny4</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165902</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>FannyMOI</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>M</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208170000</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>FannyMOI</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208170050</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Cmoi2</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165829</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Jesuis3</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
    </PatientsPN>
...
</Root>
```

I would like to sort my PatientsNP first by ID and then take the higher TimeStamp of each ID.
My output :

```
<Root>
<PatientsPN>
 <Patient>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
<Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208170050</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Cmoi2</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
<Patient>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165829</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Jesuis3</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
<Patient>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165910</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny4</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
</PatientsPN>
</Root>
```

First, I tried to sort my list by ID and then parsing through each node and use Xpath to extract the higher timestamp but that didn't work. It kept repeating the other nodes.

Also tried Muench sorting method but I couldn't make it work properly with something more generic.

My XSL is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="mark">PN</xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/*">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="substring(name(), (string-length(name()) - string-length($mark)) + 1) = $mark">
                    <!-- Search for an ID tag -->
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:if test="node()/ID">
<xsl:for-each select="node()">
                                <xsl:sort select="ID" order="ascending" />
<!-- So far everything I've done here failed -->
<xsl:for-each select=".[ID = '1']">
                                <xsl:copy>
                                  <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(number(TimeStamp) &lt; (preceding-sibling::node()/TimeStamp | following-sibling::node()/TimeStamp))]"/>
                                  </xsl:copy>
                                </xsl:for-each>
<!-- This is just an example, I don't want to have ID = 1 and ID = 2 -->
</xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="not(node()/ID)">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(number(TimeStamp) &lt; (preceding-sibling::node()/TimeStamp | following-sibling::node()/TimeStamp))]"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance for all the help you could bring me !

**EDIT :**

I'm really sorry folks I should have mentionned that I wanted to make it as generic as possible. In my example I'm talking about PatientsPN but what I'm trying to do really is that matches every PARENT nodes ending with PN (hence the ends-with copycat version of the XSL 1.0).

You are really amazing anyway, I couldn't expect more coming from you. Thanks !

**SOLUTION**
After remodeling the solution given by Dimitre, I came up with this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="kPatById" match="*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]/*" 
use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID)"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]">
 <xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
 <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]/node()[TimeStamp &lt; key('kPatById', concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID))/TimeStamp]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does the job wonderfully and it allows me to have multiple  Parent nodes that are going to be treated and sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can be as simple as that**:

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPatById" match=
 "*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]/Patient"
  use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Patient">
    <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*['PN' = substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1)]
     /Patient
       [TimeStamp &lt; key('kPatById', concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID))/TimeStamp]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
....
    <PatientsPN>
        <Patient>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165910</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny4</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165902</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>FannyMOI</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>M</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208170000</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>FannyMOI</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208170050</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Cmoi2</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <TimeStamp>20111208165829</TimeStamp>
            <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
            <PrenomPatient>Jesuis3</PrenomPatient>
            <Sexe>F</Sexe>
        </Patient>
    </PatientsPN>
...
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Root>
....
    <Patient>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <TimeStamp>20111208165819</TimeStamp>
      <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
      <PrenomPatient>Fanny</PrenomPatient>
      <Sexe>F</Sexe>
   </Patient>
   <Patient>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <TimeStamp>20111208170050</TimeStamp>
      <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
      <PrenomPatient>Cmoi2</PrenomPatient>
      <Sexe>F</Sexe>
   </Patient>
   <Patient>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <TimeStamp>20111208165829</TimeStamp>
      <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
      <PrenomPatient>Jesuis3</PrenomPatient>
      <Sexe>F</Sexe>
   </Patient>
   <Patient>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <TimeStamp>20111208165910</TimeStamp>
      <NomPatient>Dudule</NomPatient>
      <PrenomPatient>Fanny4</PrenomPatient>
      <Sexe>F</Sexe>
   </Patient>
...
</Root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Matching any element with name that ends with `"PN"` -- using a combination of `substring()` and `string-length()`.
2. Overriding the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
3. Sorting, but **not using any Muenchian grouping**.
4. Using a key to get all records of the same patient under the same `xxxPN` parent.
5. "Simple" maximum (without sorting).
6. Proper pattern matching to exclude any unwanted record.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

The XSLT 2.0 solution I find best is almost the same as the XSLT 1.0 solution above, but may be more efficient:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPatById" match="*[ends-with(name(),'PN')]/Patient"
          use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[ends-with(name(),'PN')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Patient">
    <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[ends-with(name(),'PN')]
     /Patient
        [number(TimeStamp)
        lt
          max((key('kPatById', concat(generate-id(..), '|', ID))
                                             /TimeStamp/xs:double(.)))
        ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's really impressive, thank you ! But I'm sorry I didn't quite explained my problem very well. I can't really have an xsl key matching a predefined node because I won't be able to know my name nodes.

Comment: @bosam: I updated both solutions to implement your new requirements. Please, don't go on with new requirements. Just accept (click on the check-mark next to the answer) the best answer to this good question, then ask a new question. I likie your question, +1.

Comment: I updated your code (see main post) and It works wonderfully. Thanks a lot and thanks everybody for your help. You saved me big time ! Post marked as solved by this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer (didn't check) seems to be correct, but i couldn't resist posting a XSLT 1.0 version that does not use the 'evil' for-each keyword.

The sorting is done by concatinating the ID and timestamp before sorting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="PatientsPN">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Patient">
        <xsl:sort select="concat(ID,TimeStamp)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Patient">
    <xsl:if test="not(ID=following-sibling::Patient/ID)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: @_Marvin Smit: But your solution *does use* the "evil" `<xsl:if>` and is waaay tooo  looong :)

Comment: Your solution is nice but I don't know if you have seen in my example that I'm trying to make it generic. In my example I'm talking about PatientsPN but what I'm trying to do really is that matches every nodes ending with PN (hence the ends-with copycat version of the XSL 1.0). I should have specified it in the question, sorry i'm adding it now.

Comment: :D Love the love on SO! Critisism without nastyness is the way to improvement!
Although I could have moved the "IF test" into the select of the apply-templates. :) I just thought the "ID+TimeStamp" sort + "get latest entry of all unique ID's was a funny way to solve it :)